# CakePHP only works on Mac local when using VirtualHost

Tags: macos, apache, .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite

I have a CakePHP 2.x app here: `/Users/cameron/Sites/ExampleApplication`

And inside it has the standard structure:

```
/app
 /webroot

etc.
```

However when I go to:

`localhost/~cameron/ExampleApplication`

I get the error: `The requested URL /Users/cameron/Sites/ExampleApplication/app/webroot/ was not found on this server.`

However if I setup a VirtualHost like:

```
<Directory "/Users/cameron/Sites">
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride All
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "/Users/cameron/Sites/ExampleApplication"
  ServerName example.com
  UseCanonicalName Off
</VirtualHost>
```

It works fine!

Any ideas why it works for the VirtualHost but NOT when accessing it via the usual localhost?

Here is what is inside the three .htaccess files:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
 </IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you use Mamp, you have to configure the htaccess file
and modify htaccess in folder root /  app/webroot and app/config

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase / "production" or /nameFolder/ "dev"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```